# How to render a Rails partial when receiving an update from PrivatePub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, private-pub

I have action in my application controller `application_controller.rb`

```
before_filter :activity

def track_activity(user, trackable, action = params[:action], author = current_user)
  Activity.create! user: user, trackable: trackable, action: action, author: author
  PrivatePub.publish_to("/notifications", activity: activity)
end

def activity
  @activities = current_user.activities.includes(:author, :trackable).order(created_at: :desc) if signed_in?      
end
```

it generates notifications for users when another user wrote comment or permorm other actions.

I have my partial in
views/activities/_activity.html.erb

```
<div class="activity activity_open" id="activity">
  <% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= link_to activity.user.name, activity.user %>
    <%= render "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}", activity: activity %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= subscribe_to "/notificatons" %>
```

its call on /layouts/_header.html.erb

```
<%= render @activities %>
```

and now a need publish_to("/notifications") with Private_pub gem new trac_activity when other user create comment but i dont know how do this

I need to do this

```
<% publish_to "/notifications" do %>
  $("#activity").append("<%= j render(@activities) %>");
<% end %>
```

and i don't know where I need save file if my action in application controller and it doesn't have a form with remote: true

Comment: You code is quite strange. You are publishing to /notifications in two different points: a view and in the controller in the method track_activity. Which one are you using?

Comment: Why are you performing a loop inside _activity? It should render just one activity object not many

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is probably to push generic activity data to the users listening on `/notifications` channel.

Your method is fine (the first one):

`PrivatePub.publish_to("/notifications", activity: activity)`

Now you need to write an handler for it in the view. Something like:

```
<%= subscribe_to "/notifications" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  PrivatePub.subscribe("/notifications", function(data, channel) {
     alert(data.activity);
  });
</script>
```

and within the subscribe javascript method you will do whatever you want.

You can't actually call another `<%=j render ...%>` because this is Ruby code and you are in a javascript client-side method, so you have two options here:

1. Render the `_activity.html.erb` fragment somewhere, put it in a javascript variable and replace the content when it comes through PrivatePub
2. If the fragment is not really complex use Javascript to build it: but you will need to keep mantained this layout in two different points
3. Use something like [Mustache](https://github.com/mustache/mustache). See the [RailsCast about it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/295-sharing-mustache-templates).

I think I would go for option 2 but it depends from the complexity of the partial.

Check with the Browser Console that faye is active and the socket is open to be sure that everything is working fine and I suggest you to use 
`PrivatePub.publish_to(...) rescue nil` if the data are not really important so you will not have an exception just because faye server is down.

Comment: all works but dosn't do this  $("#activity").append("<%= j render(@activities) %>"); because i dont know where add this script

Comment: You can't execute this piece of code. You must use javascript and, if you want, something like mustaches to accomplish it.
Just build the same fragment with Javascript, maybe putting the partial `_activity` in a sort of javascript variable.